# Google API throwing error when verifying token

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-signin, guzzle

I've been trying to use the Google-API for Google Sign-In, but when I do

```
// $token is set to a correct value beforehand
require_once 'inc/google-api/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => '280452639491-s53psco36kn5cm3nitma4gpqsq9ik3ao.apps.googleusercontent.com']);
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($token);
```

as instructed [by google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth), this error pops up:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 
'Guzzle requires cURL, the allow_url_fopen ini setting, or a custom HTTP handler.'
```

My Website is hosted on bplaced, which uses php 5.5.21 and I downloaded the google-api-php54 package from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases, which I required as seen above.

Comment: I suggest that something requires cURL and you should install it.

Comment: ok I think I know what happened, but unfortunately, since I'm on a free hoster, I can't enable cURL - but I will open a new question for further information

Comment: You do get what you pay for! I use [DigialOcean](http://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=c3c54945a041) which starts at $5 a month. They're great if you don't mind setting up your own host from nothing.