# Use Google-Sign In without http requests

Tags: php, google-api, httprequest, google-signin

I want to use Google-Sign in and I need to validify the token on the server when logging in. However, since I'm on a free hoster, I can't make any kind of http-request. But judging by the [integrity criteria google provides](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth), it doesn't really seem necessary to me, only for getting google's public keys maybe...

I've described on this question, how I set up my Sign-in:
[Google API throwing error when verifying token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299560/google-api-throwing-error-when-verifying-token) 
What I'm asking for now is a way to circumvent the request, so I can validify the token...

Comment: First: why can't you do a http request if your code is hosted?

Comment: Second: how do you want to use a web api without doing a http request?

Comment: I've downloaded the library onto my server, so it should be able to verify on itself, and I can't do a http request because I can neither use cURL nor file_get_contents on external services - also see the question I linked

Comment: And how does that library do the request if it cannot perform a http request? By telepathy?

Comment: afaik, it is not necessary to perform a request, since, if you look here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token
these are simple comparison operations

Comment: Sorry, but you did not understand how this works. Just because you use some library does not mean that the communication with googles systems works like magic. It is the library that does the requests for you, that is all the difference. How would you expect the library to communicate with the google systems?

Comment: Which of the points requires communication with the google systems?